# How can improve application performance in S3

Tags: android, performance, calendar, freeze, samsung-mobile

The app is ready to be published. At this time i found a critical performance issue in S3 device only. The app is all about pager, swiping through pager and listing Calendar events by selecting date from our custom calendar. All is going smooth in other devices excepts Samsung Galaxy S3 and due to this after being some time in application during navigation it freezes application and black screen appeared. Apart from this sometimes it doesn't load data on adapter to display Calendar events. how should i treat this crisis while i am not considering delay in publishing the app. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: i think you have a memory leak in your application, you can detect that with memory monitor in android studio , I think you have this issue in all Samsung device, as i had this problem, if you have use bitmap you need handle that by self, like set null in your `imageView`

Comment: Are you using a Page Transformer on your viewpager? I had exactly the same issue also with the Samsung Galaxy S3. I had to remove the page transformer and that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. If you are using a `PageTransformer`, I ended up doing this to fix the issue. Not sure if other Samsung models have the same issue, only found it on the S3.

```
//Do a check to see if the device model does not support the PageTransformer
if (!CommonUtil.isUnsupportedModel()) {
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
    }
}
```